# Flutter Web, debug in https?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, flutter-web

One of the functions of my application requires the ability to record. Chrome won't let non-secure sites access the microphone.

I can use, and have been using, `flutter build web --profile --dart-define=Dart2jsOptimization=O0` for this and pointing an IIS site at the `...../build/web`, but my app takes 1-2.5 minutes to build each time. Really slows down the workflow of minor adjustments.

Is there a way to `run` to an https server?

Answer (score 2):

I have also checked for how to run flutter web with secure server but not found any way. But I still manage to use microphone by using below method.

To ignore Chrome’s secure origin policy, follow these steps.

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` in Chrome.
2. Find and enable the `Insecure origins treated as secure` section.
3. Add any addresses you want to ignore the secure origin policy for.
4. Remember to include the port number too (if required).
5. Save and restart Chrome.

Note: Don't forget to turn it disable after your work is done.