How to run camera on mobile browser with flutter web app
I want to access camera in my flutter web app and I have created a small demo. It is working fine in macbook chrome browser. However, when I try to access it using the mobile chrome browser I get below error.  I could not find any example which achieves this. I am using below dependencies
camera: ^0.11.0+1
video_player: ^2.8.6



Are you sure that chrome on mobile has permission to access the camera?

@AhmadF Yes I specifically enabled it.

The issue was that I was running the web app on http instead of https.
Followed the steps on the below link to enable http as secure for testing purpose and it started working.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76305720/1275683
